# Go + Redis - Tutorial Get Started doesn't work

Tags: go, redis

**Hi,**

I have made several redis and go tutorial sites.
Most of the pages don't work.
Here's a very simple one that doesn't work.

https://developer.redis.com/develop/golang/

And here is the error message.

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:17:29: too many arguments in call to client.cmdable.Ping
    have (context.Context)
    want ()
```

How to make the tutorial work?

Comment: use import `"github.com/go-redis/redis/v8"`

Comment: OK. It works. I don't understand how this was guessed but it works. without v8, the tutorial did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of go-redis are you using? In version 8 it should work.
`github.com/go-redis/redis/v8`.

See this example code on how to use it: https://github.com/go-redis/redis/blob/master/example_test.go

In `v1` of `go-redis` the function signature does not include `context.Context`. [See the code](https://github.com/go-redis/redis/blob/4ea3e7531bf719b02630a8712cb66b5b1bc37f8e/commands.go#L33). You've most likely imported go redis without the v8 suffix, thus importing go-redis v1. (in go the v1 version of a library does not require the `v...` suffix).

Comment: OK. It works. I don't understand how this was guessed but it works. without v8, the tutorial did not work.

Comment: You've probably imported 'github.com/go-redis/redis'. Note the missing`v8` suffix. Without it, you've imported to v1 of go-redis. In v1, the function signature of `Ping` does not include a context. See the v1 code here: https://github.com/go-redis/redis/blob/4ea3e7531bf719b02630a8712cb66b5b1bc37f8e/commands.go#L33